# Constant circular motion: understanding $\underline{e_{\theta}}=\frac{d(\underline{e_r})}{d\theta}$

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics, mathematical-astronomy, celestial-mechanics

**Context:** 1st year BSc Mathematics, Vectors and Mechanics module, constant circular motion.

This may be trivial, but can someone tell me what's wrong with the following reasoning?

$$\underline{e_r}=\underline{i}\cos\theta+\underline{j}\sin\theta=(1,\theta) \;\;(1);$$
$$\underline{e_\theta}=\frac{d(\underline{e_r})}{d\theta}=-\underline{i}\sin\theta+\underline{j}\cos\theta \;\;(2);$$
so
$$(1),(2):\;\; \underline{e_\theta}=\frac{d}{d\theta}((1,\theta))=(1,\frac{d\theta}{d\theta})=(1,1) \;\;(3),$$
so
$$(2),(3): \;\; (1,1)=-\underline{i}\sin\theta+\underline{j}\cos\theta \;\; (4),$$
an undesirable conclusion.

Comment: Your notation in the right hand side of (1) is confusing. Given a basis, you can expand any vector into it's components. In that case $e_r$ would have components (1,0). In any case derivative of the vector is not at all the same as derivative of the components.

Comment: @lcv $(1,\theta)$ is meant to be a pair of polar coordinates. Is the middle step of (3) false given that?

Comment: How are you going from $\frac{d}{d\theta}(1,\theta)$ to $(1,\frac{d\theta}{d\theta})$? Those are not equal.

Comment: @runway44 That may be a problem. They look to me like they should be equal, since $r$ is constant w.r.t. $\theta$. Can you say why they aren't?

Comment: I can, but why should I? It strikes me as bizarre to expect they should be equal. The derivative of $(r,\theta)$ is not supposed to be the derivative in each component (in which case the derivative of $r$ should be $0$, but whatever), it is the velocity vector *itself* written in polar coordinates. If you're going in a circle, at constant speed, the velocity vector is perpendicular to current position (and thus also changing). Obviously the rate of change of $\theta$ with respect to $\theta$ is $1$, but that's different from the angle *of* the velocity vector.

Comment: (I guess I technically shouldn't call it a velocity vector since the derivative isn't with respect to time but my point is still the same.)

Comment: @runway44 Do you mean the angle of the velocity vector is measured w.r.t. a circle centred on the moving particle, not w.r.t. the circle given by the particle's path around its centre of orbit?

Comment: The angle of the velocity vector is measured with respect to the same origin and positive axis everything is being measured with respect to for the polar coordinates. One doesn't need to mention circles. (I guess you have to draw the velocity vector as emanating from the origin instead of emanating from the point itself, if that's what you mean.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $\displaystyle \frac{d}{d\theta}(r,\theta)=\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta},\frac{d\theta}{d\theta}\right)$ is not valid if $(r,\theta)$ is not Cartesian.

Note $(r,\theta)$ is supposed to represent the position $\vec{r}$, which is a function of the angle $\theta$ from some chosen origin and positive axis in a 2D plane. The derivative $d\vec{r}/d\theta$ is supposed to be interpreted as

$$ \frac{d\vec{r}}{d\theta}= \lim_{\Delta\theta\to0}\frac{\Delta\vec{r}}{\Delta\theta}. \tag{$\ast$}$$

Note $\Delta\vec{r}$ is vector displacement, and the vector displacement between $(r_1,\theta_1)$ and $(r_2,\theta_2)$ is *not* given in polar form by the formula $(r_2-r_1,\theta_2-\theta_1)$. If $r_1=r_2$ then obviously the "rotational displacement" i.e. the amount of rotation to go from one to the other is $\theta_2-\theta_1$, but the derivative $(\ast)$ describes the linear displacement in polar coordinates. For instance, if $\theta=t$ (so a point particle is going around the origin at constant unit speed), then the derivative is just the velocity vector, $d\vec{r}/d\theta=d\vec{r}/dt=\vec{v}$.

The angular component of $\vec{v}$ does not describe how $\theta$ is changing (i.e. it is not $d\theta/d\theta$), it says which direction the particle is moving. Similarly, radial component of $\vec{v}$ describes the speed, which is different from $dr/d\theta$ since the particle may have a non-radial component to its movement. The radical component of $\vec{v}$ would only match $dr/dt$ if it is (at a given moment) moving entirely radially, in which case $d\theta=0$ anyway. Also in this case, if $\theta$ is constant, the direction of movement is the same as the direction of position, so the angular component of $\vec{v}$ is also $\theta$, not $0$.

Comment: Couple of questions. 1) Why would having a rotational displacement of $\theta_2-\theta_1$ depend on having $r_1=r_2$? It seems to me that $r$ can vary as much as you like without affecting rotational displacement. 2) Picturing $\Delta\underline{r}$ as a chord subtending $\Delta\theta$, would it be fair to say the following? For constant $r$, we have $\frac{d}{d\theta}{((r,\theta))}=\lim_{\Delta\theta\rightarrow 0}\frac{\text{crd}\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}=\lim_{\Delta\theta\rightarrow 0}\frac{2\sin\frac{\Delta\theta}{2}}{2\frac{\Delta\theta}{2}}=1$ (by sandwich rule).

Comment: (1) It doesn't. (2) Automatically no since $(r,\theta)$ represents a vector whereas the chord length is a scalar. However if you mean the magnitude of the derivative, then yes you can say $\|\Delta\vec{r}\|$ is the chord length, which is missing an $r$ in your formula, in which case you get $\|d\vec{r}/d\theta\|=r$ for constant $r$.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, most non-Cartesian coordinates don't let us just differentiate the coordinates characterizing a unit vector, whether we try all of them or a plausible subset. For a generally viable treatment, it helps to treat the $\theta$ subscript in $\underline{e}_\theta$ as a parameter and write the vector as a rotation of the $\theta=0$ case, say $\underline{e}_\theta=R_\theta\underline{e}_0$, so$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\underline{e}_\theta=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\underline{e}_{\theta+h}-\underline{e}_\theta}{h}=R_\theta\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\underline{e}_{h}-\underline{e}_0}{h},$$a calculation I've made easier to read by placing the polar subscript outside the underline. To prove $\frac{d}{d\theta}\underline{e}_\theta=\underline{e}_{\theta-\pi/2}$, it suffices to check the case $\theta=0$, which can be done with a diagram instead of Cartesian coordinates.